# Transmission web interface download directory different from transmission-daemon

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, transmission, torrent, transmission-daemon

I'm trying to make transmission download on an external drive using a RaspberryPi with Raspbian installed on a sd card.
I followed various tutorials and finally I managed to set all the permissions in order to get transmission doing the job.
However, despite I set the complete and incomplete downloads directories in transmission-daemon/settings.json, the transmission web gui seems to have his own settings. 
I did change it in the settings section of the web gui but I'd like to "bind" the default directories of the daemon and the web gui.

How should I proceed?

Note that in the web gui you can only set the final folder, not the "incomplete downloads" one so I'm afraid the sd card will fill up very quickly.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Stop Transmission first. Change the settings.json file. Start Transmission.